# Intellisense is not recognizing my 2 dimensional list when using Item[X, Y]

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert some old Delphi code (a dijkstra path finding algoritme) to C#. I used arrays in Delphi, but since C# doesn't allow dynamic resizing I have taken to use two dimensional lists.

But where I expect to find my PathCoord class at Map[X, Y], Visual studio keeps telling me there is "no overload for method 'this' takes 2 arguments". And either intellisense is either giving me the dropdown for another list or it is just giving me the four options for a basic object non defined object.

I am most likely overlooking something completely obvious, but I have been looking at this for hours and starting to think I'm staring myself blind.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class PathCoord
{
    List<Point> PathTo;
    Color TheColor;
    double Cost;

    public PathCoord()
    {
        PathTo = new List<Point>();
        TheColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Cost = 0f;
    }

}

public class PathEngine
{
    public List<List<PathCoord>> Map = new List<List<PathCoord>>();

    public void AddPathToPoint(Point newPoint, List<Point> PathTo, double Cost)
    {

        Map[newPointX, newPoint.Y].
    }
}
```

This is the shortest possible code example. I thought it best not to include too much code, but I will happily include the whole if requested

Comment: Pretty sure it's because you need to do `[][]` instead of `[,]`. Finding a good duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Map` field is not a 2-dimensional array. That would look like this:

```cs
PathCoord[,] Map = new PathCoord[2, 5];
```

Not only that, but your `Map` isn't an array at all, but a dynamic `List` collection. There is no such thing as a "multidimentional list" in C# (at least, not in the sense that multidimensional arrays exist like the above).

Instead, your `Map` is a nested list, or a list of lists. As such, you need to use the "jagged array" approach of using multiple indexers - one for each level of lists:

```cs
Map[newPointX][newPointY] = ...;
```

Comment: Thanks to both Abion47 and gunr2171 for the help. I had been trying that as well but was still getting the same compiler error yesterday. It works now though, I guess maybe a VS restart was needed.

Sadly I do not have enough reputation to upvote your answer.